# updating an array in the view using ng-repeat angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to update my array and rendering it in the view. After reading and looking at example it appears $apply is the solution. However how to apply it in the controller is has me confused.

Template

```
  <div ng-controller="Controller">
        <div ng-repeat="customer in listcustomers |orderBy:'-age'">

            <table class="box-table" width="100%">
                 <tr>
                   <th>Name:{{customer.name}}</th>
                   <th>Age:{{customer.age}}</th>
                 </tr>
            </table>

        </div>

        <div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="enter a name" ng-model="customer.name" name="customer_name">
            <input type="text" placeholder="enter a age" ng-model="customer.age" name="customer_age">
            <button type="submit" ng-click="addCustomer(customer_name,customer_age)">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>

controller

angular.module('myApp').
controller("Controller",["$scope", function($scope){

    $scope.customer = [

         {
            name: 'Drew',
            age: 30
         },

         {
            name: 'Meike',
            age: 54
         },

        {
            name: 'Peter',
            age: 25
        },
        {
            name: 'Alex',
            age: 44
        }
    ];

    $scope.addCustomer = function(customer_name,customer_age){

        var person = {
            name: customer_name,
            age: customer_age
        };

        $scope.customer.push(person);
        console.log("Person was added: "+person);
    }

}])
    .directive("myNames",function(){
        return{
            restrict : 'E',
            transclude : false,
            templateUrl: 'pages/myNames.html',
            scope: {
                listcustomers: "="
            }
        };
    });
```

index.html

```
<div ng-controller="Controller">
      <my-names listcustomers='customer' add-Customer='addCustomer'></my-names>
  </div>
```

The array is being updated. I confirm by printing out the array in the console. The issue is it is not being updated in the view.

Comment: can you provide plunkr

Comment: `addCustomer(customer_name,customer_age)` should be `addCustomer(customer.name, customer.age)`. $apply is not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have molded your code to the some extend as it wasn't properly managed and it is working fine now for me.

**index.html**

```
 <div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
        <div ng-repeat="c in listCustomers |orderBy:'-age'">

            <table class="box-table" width="100%">
                 <tr>
                   <th>Name:{{c.name}}</th>
                   <th>Age:{{c.age}}</th>
                 </tr>
            </table>

        </div>

        <div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="enter a name" ng-model="customer.name" name="customer_name">
            <input type="text" placeholder="enter a age" ng-model="customer.age" name="customer_age">
            <button type="submit" ng-click="addCustomer(customer.name, customer.age)">Submit</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js"></script>
<script src="../app.js"></script>
```

**app.js**

```
var MyApp = angular.module('myApp', [])

MyApp.controller("MyController",["$scope", function($scope){

    $scope.customer = {name:'', age:''};
    $scope.listCustomers = [

         {
            name: 'Drew',
            age: 30
         },

         {
            name: 'Meike',
            age: 54
         },

        {
            name: 'Peter',
            age: 25
        },
        {
            name: 'Alex',
            age: 44
        }
    ];

    $scope.addCustomer = function(customerName,customerAge){
            var data = {name:customerName, age:customerAge};
            $scope.listCustomers.push(data);
            console.log("Person was added: "+$scope.customer);
    }

}])
    .directive("myNames",function(){
        return{
            restrict : 'E',
            transclude : false,
            templateUrl: 'pages/myNames.html',
            scope: {
                listcustomers: "="
            }
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not receiving your values as you expect. This is shown in your console output if you try to access one of the properties.

Instead, create an object on scope with the new customer data. When clicking submit, you just copy this on to the array.
Further more, your posted code are not without errors. You repeat on `listcustomers` but push to `customer`?

I've modified your code in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Sym8052LmKvwL4JIZ757?p=preview)

Here is the idea.

```
angular.module('myApp', []).
controller("Controller", ["$scope", function($scope) {

  $scope.customers = [...];

  $scope.newCustomer = {};

  $scope.addCustomer = function() {   
    $scope.customers.push($scope.newCustomer);
  }
}]);
```

And in your HTML

```
<input type="text" ng-model="newCustomer.name">
<input type="text" ng-model="newCustomer.age">
<button type="submit" ng-click="addCustomer()">Submit</button>
```

I've stripped the unnecessary parts away.

Answer (score 0):

Since you create isolated scope and name your variable listcustomer

```
scope: {
    listcustomers: "="
}
```

you should use that variable to push new values to your array:

```
 $scope.addCustomer = function(customer_name,customer_age){

        var person = {
            name: customer_name,
            age: customer_age
        };

        $scope.listcustomers.push(person); // HERE
        console.log("Person was added: "+person);
    }
```